# Query by association and Impact to Model

Tags: postgresql, associations, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I currently have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  has_many :reviews
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I wanted to be able to query Reviews.where(blah blah) and then filter by columns in the Location model.

I have two questions.
1. Do I need to update my model to enable this?
2. If I change my model, does it destroy the current records I already have today in my db?

This is the updated model that I'm guessing I'll need.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  has_many :reviews, through: :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Any articles or help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way you did your model it feels like the user own the location, i would have done it differently:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :visited_places, through: :reviews, source: :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, :user
  attr_accessible :description, :rank, etc....
end
```

This way a user has many locations through reviews, you could say those locations are places he visited.
A location can have many review but of course doesn't belong to any user.
A review is written by a user and concern a place.

With this model you can get all reviews written by a given User or related to a specific location for instance such as Review.joins(:user).where(username: "toto") or Review.joins(:location).where(location_name: "Hong Kong")

Comment: Hi Typpex, in my app the Location is indeed owned by the User and the Reviews are for the User as well, but the customers leaving the reviews are leaving the Review at the Location level which gets stored to the User. 

I need to now search the reviews but filter certain criteria at the Location model level. 

Any recommendations on the best way to set up these models?  How will it effect the existing data I already have on file?

Comment: Can you describe what kind of search you would like to do on a review exactly? With them model i put in the answer you can filter review by location, user already :)

Comment: Ah, I was asking how to do my search if I did not change my model and kept it the way it is.  If I have to change my model, (which I'm open to) how does it affect my existing data and what's the best way to update the data so the association keys are in sync?